# Excel IF statement requires one of two entries in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula that looks up entries in cells and returns 'complete' if values in all cells are 'Yes', otherwise the formula returns 'incomplete' if any cell has 'No':

```
=IF(AND(F3="Yes",  G3="Yes", H3 = "Yes", I3= "Yes", J3 =" Yes", K3 =" Yes"), "Complete", "Incomplete")
```

For column I this cell could also contain 'N/A', so I want to update the formula for I3 if it is 'Yes' or 'N/A' then this is to be considered 'Yes'.

I cannot find any solution online is anyone able to advise?

Comment: Replace `I3= "Yes"` with `OR(I3= "Yes", ISNA(I3))`

Comment: is 'N/A' text or the result of a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L3</kbd>

```
=IF(BYROW(IFNA(F3:K5,"Yes")="Yes",AND),"Complete","InComplete")
```

---

Or, if you are not in `MS365` Beta Channel version then

```
=IF(BYROW(IFNA(F3:K5,"Yes")="Yes",LAMBDA(x,AND(x))),"Complete","InComplete")
```

---

**Note:** It is assumed `#N/A` is a formula returned and not a text value.

---

Or, without using a <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=IF(MMULT(N(IFNA(F3:K5,"Yes")="Yes"),SEQUENCE(6)^0)=6,"Complete","InComplete")
```

---

And ensuring that if `N/A` is a text then :

[image]

---

```
=IF(BYROW(IFNA(IF(F3:K5="N/A","Yes",F3:K5),"Yes")="Yes",AND),"Complete","InComplete")
```

---

Also, I using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd> will be a good option, if you are not using `MS365`

[image]

---

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(IFNA(IF(F3:K3="N/A","Yes",F3:K3),"Yes")="Yes"))=6,"Complete","InComplete")
```

---